# Having a issue with 2 users logging into ADFS on the same PC

Tags: .net, adfs

We have a .net web application that is sets as relying party for our customers ADFS which is hosted in their environment. We are having a issue where the First user logs in, does something then logs out. Then the Second user logs in shortly after on the same computer and is now logged in as the First user. I have tried removing all cookies and session items but for some reason they keep getting logged in as the user First user. This only occurs when the 2 users use the same computer and login right after each other.

Has anyone experienced this before and if so how did you fix this.

thanks